# gatsby-plugin-image and GraphQL don't recognize my image frontmatter when .mdx is outside of /pages/ directory

Tags: graphql, gatsby, yaml-front-matter

BACKGROUND:

I am programmatically creating pages with .mdx files within `/src/content/` using page layout templates. Everything is working perfectly until I need to grab the image from the .mdx file's frontmatter formatted like so:

example: /src/content/.../.../hello-world.mdx

```
---
title: foo
image: ../images/icon.png
---
hello world.
```

I have the plugins gatsby-plugin-image, gatsby-plugin-sharp, gatsby-source-filesystem, and gatsby-transformer-sharp all installed and referenced in my `gatsby-config.js`. Furthermore, I have my `gatsby-config.js` file set up with gatsby-source-filesystem's options to look for .mdx files within `/src/content`.

THE PROBLEM:

Gatsby states [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/using-gatsby-plugin-image#dynamic-images) that "Any GraphQL File object that includes an image will have a childImageSharp field that you can use to query the image data." However that isn't happening for me:
[image]

It simply sees the `image:` key in the frontmatter as a string and never gives it the `childImageSharp` fields. Attempting to force the query by writing out the fields anyway just results in errors.

HOWEVER!!!

If I take that same .mdx file and place it within `/src/pages` suddenly gatsby-plugin-image starts operating correctly and gives the `childImageSharp` fields:

[image]

WHY?

UPDATE: placing .mdx file into `/src/content/` works and childImageSharp fields appear in GraphQL, but .mdx files placed anywhere deeper (ex: `src/content/recipes/guacamole/`) do not work.

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER:

`../images/icon.png` is not a valid path for a file living in `/src/content/recipes/guac/` to be referencing an image that lives in `/src/images/`. The correct path that my image key should have in the .mdx frontmatter should be *relative to the .mdx's location* (ex: `image: ../../../images/icon.png`).

MY PATH WAS WRONG. Therefore GraphQL did not recognize it as a file and did not create the childImageSharp fields.